# sync folder from ec2 to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization

I'm trying to synchronize a folder from a windows instance of EC2 to a S3 bucket.
Although 'AWS Sync' command is a nice idea, but I want to host the command to somewhere else (like rundeck or there's some other place in ASW?) rather than on that EC2 instance. Is there some good way to do this? Thanks.

-Regards,
Aaron

Comment: Have your thought thru how "somewhere else" will access the files on your EC2 instance?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, maybe though windows share folder or some other AWS mechanism?

Comment: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/aws-s3-steps

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? That is, where do you wish to copy the data **from** and where do you wish to copy it **to**? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I'm trying to copy data from a folder in EC2 and it's a windows server 2012. The files will be copied to a specific bucket in AWS S3.

Comment: Then use the `aws s3 sync` command from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing else will have access to the files on the EC2 server unless you explicitly setup some sort of file sharing thing, but then the question becomes less about AWS and more about some sort of Windows file sharing software. Nothing will be able to copy the files to S3 as fast as a command running directly on the EC2 server.

If you want to run an `aws s3 sync` command on the EC2 server, but trigger it from some process outside the server, you can look into the [Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/run-command/) feature of the [AWS Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/).

If you want to run the synchronize task on a set schedule, then you could use Windows Task Scheduler on the server to trigger the `aws s3 sync` command.